# How to launch clips from instrument in Ableton Live to USB audio interface for recording

Tags: audio-recording, audio-interfaces, ableton-live

I am trying to record for YouTube and a podcast with a dynamic mic plugged into a 2-channel Presonus USB audio interface. I would also like to launch audio clips from a Monome grid 64-key controller that is running through Ableton live. I can hear the audio clips on my end, but the audio sent out does not pick up the clips, only the audio from the mic, and the clips can't be heard in the recording.

I have set the audio input and output as the USB audio interface in Ableton Live, and we are recording audio through Discord as my co-host and I are remote. In Discord, the input and output are also both set to audio box USB.

What I can't figure out since I am new to this is the settings necessary to get the clips from Ableton Live out through Discord so that we can have them on our recordings. If anyone has advice, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your issue is that your audio output is going to a hardware device instead of Discord’s virtual device. You may see a Discord virtual device where you can send all your audio from ableton (discord is probably picking up from the interface and not at all from ableton currently).

On windows you can try VoiceMeeter, macOS Loopback or Soundflower and making virtual devices in Midi Audio Setup or whatever